# Reactstrap documentation

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I've never used bootstrap or reactstrap and i'm having a hard time understand the documentation.

For exemple i'm trying to change Navbar color and background opacity but since they have reserved keywords to pass as props i don't know where to find them or how does it work! the only thing that worked with Color was `color = " white"`. 
I tried to change it using css but it doesn't work i even tried to use the !important but nothing too. 
Here's their documentation:

[image: documentation Navbar]

They are using Bootsrap 4

Comment: Can you put your code in Codesanbox or somewhere? Maybe problem came from your code, not reactstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `color` attribute you mention here comes from bootstrap conventions. They try to limit the use of some attributes using enums. For instance, the color attribute accepts values such as "primary", "secondary", "warning", "danger" etc.

See here for more details: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/alerts/

I suspect "white" didn't actually work, but rather appeared so. "white" is not in the enum list as far as I know.

The way to customize colors is to change what the "primary", "success", etc colors are. 
This helps us to theme a website rather than using random colors all over the website. Using themes help us a lot during the latter part of the website journey.

Answer (score 1):

color property is a className. 
Create a class `pink-color`, for example, set `background-color`:

```
.pink-color {
    background-color: #f7009d !important;
}
```

Use this `pink-color` class as a value for color property.

```
<Navbar color='pink-color' dark expand="md" fixed='top'>
```

Comment: This might work. But I personally don't think this is the right way to do it. By using random classNames for color attribute, maintenance of the website can become harder later on. I think we should stick with the in built list(primary, secondary, success etc). We can of course override those to get a different themes.